# Stuck on "sending 'userdata' (137526 KB)..."

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Yesterday I installed the Developer preview on my Nexus 7, to see how it was...
Today, trying to get back to Android, I got stuck (for around 20 minutes now) on the following:

```
root@lvandoeduardo:/home/vandoeduardo/Downloads/nakasi-jdq39# ./flash-all.sh...
(bootloader) Bootloader is already unlocked
OKAY [  0.020s]
finished. total time: 0.020s
erasing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.027s]
finished. total time: 0.027s
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'cache'...
OKAY [  0.077s]
finished. total time: 0.077s
erasing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.028s]
finished. total time: 0.028s
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.066s]
finished. total time: 0.066s
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'userdata'...
OKAY [  1.206s]
finished. total time: 1.206s
sending 'bootloader' (2096 KB)...
OKAY [  0.264s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  0.724s]
finished. total time: 0.989s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.020s]
finished. total time: 0.020s
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.sig'
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: 4.18
Baseband Version.....: N/A
Serial Number........: 015d24bc7c4bf818
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
OKAY [  0.040s]
checking version-bootloader...
OKAY [  0.023s]
sending 'boot' (4944 KB)...
OKAY [  0.635s]
writing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.174s]
sending 'recovery' (5446 KB)...
OKAY [  0.663s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.197s]
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.054s]
sending 'system' (471804 KB)...
OKAY [ 55.425s]
writing 'system'...
OKAY [ 23.372s]
erasing 'userdata'...
OKAY [  1.027s]
formatting 'userdata' partition...
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 14442037248
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 8176
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 32768
    Label: 
    Blocks: 3525888
    Block groups: 108
    Reserved block group size: 863
Created filesystem with 11/883008 inodes and 96825/3525888 blocks
sending 'userdata' (137526 KB)...
```

It just doesn't gets through it...

What can I do ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue, it even got stuck on the same number of KB. Additionally, I could not use the volume buttons to navigate in the bootloader.

I ended up powering off the device by long-pressing the power button, and the device booted succesfully into android.

```
foo@bar:~/nexus/nakasi-jdq40$ ./flash-all.sh
...
(bootloader) Bootloader is already unlocked
OKAY [  0.020s]
finished. total time: 0.020s
erasing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.020s]
finished. total time: 0.020s
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'cache'...
OKAY [  0.047s]
finished. total time: 0.047s
erasing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.021s]
finished. total time: 0.021s
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.078s]
finished. total time: 0.078s
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'userdata'...
OKAY [  1.020s]
finished. total time: 1.020s
sending 'bootloader' (2096 KB)...
OKAY [  0.322s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  0.708s]
finished. total time: 1.030s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.020s]
finished. total time: 0.020s
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.sig'
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: 4.18
Baseband Version.....: N/A
Serial Number........: 015d257880240209
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
OKAY [  0.030s]
checking version-bootloader...
OKAY [  0.020s]
sending 'boot' (4944 KB)...
OKAY [  0.753s]
writing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.183s]
sending 'recovery' (5446 KB)...
OKAY [  0.834s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.194s]
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.056s]
sending 'system' (471804 KB)...
OKAY [ 70.500s]
writing 'system'...
OKAY [ 23.343s]
erasing 'userdata'...
OKAY [  0.955s]
formatting 'userdata' partition...
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 14442037248
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 8176
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 32768
    Label:
    Blocks: 3525888
    Block groups: 108
    Reserved block group size: 863
Created filesystem with 11/883008 inodes and 96825/3525888 blocks
sending 'userdata' (137526 KB)...
```

and after the power-off:

```
FAILED (data transfer failure (Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown))
finished. total time: 502.554s
```